# Can the group $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$ be written as union of finitely many proper subgroups of it?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, infinite-groups

> I want to know if the group $G=\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$ can be written as union of finitely many proper subgroups of it ?

It is clear that $\mathbb Z$ can't be written as union of finitely many proper subgroups as the subgroups are of the form $n \mathbb Z$ for some integer $n$ and there are infinitely many primes in $\mathbb Z.$

My way to think: If possible $G= H_1 \cup \cdots\cup H_r $ where $r>1$ and $H_i's$ are proper subgroups of $G.$ Now considering the projection maps $\pi_1$ and $\pi _2$ on $G$ there exist $i$ and $j$ such that $\mathbb Z=\pi_1(H_i)$ and $\mathbb Z=\pi_2(H_j).$ I can't complete my arguments after that. Any helps will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Let $$H_{1}=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\,:\,x,y\,\text{have same parity}\}$$ $$H_{2}=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\,:\, 2\mid x\}$$
$$H_{3}=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\,:\, 2\mid y\}$$ It's easy to see that $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}=H_{1}\cup H_{2} \cup H_{3}$.

For more look up

- *[Finitely Generated Abelian Groups as Unions of Proper Subgroups](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2312836)* by A Rosenfield.  *The American Mathematical Monthly*, Vol. $70$, No. $10$ (Dec $1963$), pp. $1070-1074$

Comment: I hope it can be extended to $\mathbb Z^n$ for $n>1,$ as I can't access the paper you mentioned.

Comment: Not sure about Z^n. Added a link for the reference

Comment: If you define the same thing on the $n-$tuples it appears that $\mathbb Z^n$ is union of $n+1$ proper subgroups.

Comment: Perhaps Yes. Defining the same thing might not work though. Some subtle modifications might be required

Comment: For $K=\{(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\in \mathbb Z^{n}: x_1,\ldots,x_n \; \text{has} \;  \text{the} \;  \text{same} \;  \text{parity}\}, H_j=\{(x_1,\ldots,x_n) \in \mathbb Z^{n}: 2 | x_j\}$ for $j=1,\ldots,n.$ Then $\mathbb Z^{n}= K \cup H_1 \cup \cdots \cup H_n$ and each one is proper subgroup of $\mathbb Z^{n}.$

Comment: Yes. This works. :)

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}^n=\mathbb{Z}^2\times\mathbb{Z}^{n-2}$ can be written as union of three groups using the example from the answer. Just extend each subgroup: $H_1\times\mathbb{Z}^{n-2}, H_2\times\mathbb{Z}^{n-2}, H_3\times\mathbb{Z}^{n-2}$, right?

Answer (score 8):

> Any group $G$ with a non-cyclic finite quotient $\pi:G\to Q$ is union of finitely many proper subgroups.

Indeed, write $Q$ as union of its cyclic subgroups $Q_i$. Then $G$ is union of the $\pi^{-1}(Q_i)$, which are proper subgroups.

Note: a 1956 theorem of B.H. Neumann says that whenever a group $G$ is finite non-redundant union of subgroups $H_i$, then all $H_i$ have finite index. Hence, the only way in general is to pull from a finite quotient.

Therefore the converse of the above statement holds:

> If a group has all its finite quotients cyclic, then it is not union of finitely many proper subgroups.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following facts, which strengthen your intuition/motivation for the question.

(1) A group $G$ can be written as union of proper subgroups if and only if it is non-cyclic.

(2) Now try to get *non-cyclic* finite quotient of $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$; you can easily find (one appears in accepted answer). The quotient (being finite and non-cyclic) is union of finitely many proper subgroups; pull back them in $G$ to reach the destination.